# Problem on displaying contents of array

Tags: php, arrays

the code below saves content and images to `$varcontent[$i]["content"]` and `$vacontent[$i]["images"]` . However the only I get outside the loop that displays the content and images correctly, is `$varcontent[$i]["content"]` . Print_r shows all the data of the array including images.

```
echo $varcontent[4]["content"]; //shows the content
echo $varcontent[4]["images"] //shows the word Array
```

Comment: The code you provided would never set `$varcontent[4]`, could you provide more of your code?

Comment: @Shad Hello, I updated the code with the full one.

Comment: $varcontent[4]["images"] shows the word Array

Comment: How did you set the $varcontent[4]["images"]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to do `print_r($varcontent[4]["content"])`