# Help me on displaying the contents of array

Tags: php, regex, dom

The script gets the content and images from a blog site. A post may have 1 or more images. So what it does, it gets the content of the blog and all the images related to the post. After that, with the double foreach loop it displays the content and the images urls. I am trying to combine the current post's content and images in one or two variables. So I will be able to show the content with an easy way like a for loop and a variable like `$varcontent[$i]`

```
echo $varcontent[4]["content"]; //shows the content
echo implode('<br/>', $varcontent[4]["images"]); //shows the images
```

Comment: What should it show? An output of `Array()` implies that it's empty, and the PHP debugger probably knows what it's talking about ;)

Comment: How it's empty. `$nohtml["content"]` and `$nohtml["images"]` echo correctly the results. What I want is a variable like `$varcontent[4]["content"];` to display content+images.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509147/problem-on-displaying-contents-of-array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because `$varcontent[4]["images"]` is an array;

So need to use loop or use `implode` function of php

Use either

```
foreach($varcontent[4]["images"] as $image){
   echo  $image; echo "<br>"; 
}
```

Or

```
echo implode('<br/>', $varcontent[4]["images"]);
```

Comment: So simple! Thanks. Is there a way to save the values of for example `$varcontent[1]["content"]` and $varcontent[1]["content"]` into one variable? My purpose is to be displayed with a for loop.

Comment: @Punkis : please explain little bit more. I don't understand what do you want?

Comment: The script gets the content and images from a blog site. A post may have 1 or more images. So what it does, it gets the content of the blog and all the images related to the post. After that, with the double foreach loop it displays the content and the images urls. I am trying to combine the current post's content and images in one or two variables. So I will be able to show the content with an easy way like a for loop and a variable like `$varcontent[$i]`

Comment: foreach($varcontent as $nohtml){
     echo $nohtml["content"]; echo implode('<br/>', $nohtml["images"]); }